# JQuery on multiple objects

Tags: jquery

if we have something like this:

```
var foo=$('.foo');
var boo=$('.boo');
var koo=$('.koo');
```

Then is there any possibility to put `foo`,`boo` and `koo` in one `JQuery` object with `$` function ?

I Tried these:

```
$(foo,koo,boo).removeClass('someClass'); // nothing happened
$([foo,koo,boo]).removeClass('someClass'); // nothing happened
```

But nothing happend.

PS. I know I can use direct selector with `$('.foo,.boo,.koo')` but this is not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have several jQuery objects, you can use [$.add()](https://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
var combo = foo.add(koo).add(boo)
combo.removeClass('someClass')
```

Comment: This is what im looking for !

Answer (score 4):

You can select multiple elements like so:

```
$(".foo, .boo, .koo").removeClass('someClass');
```

This is called a multiple selector, as documented on https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

If you want to store them in a variable, you have to use the `add` method as such

```
var elements = $(".foo").add(".koo").add(".boo");
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/add/

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Edit your answer and wait, So that they can remove the vote if they want to..

Comment: I've edited my question

Comment: It's ok man, `Serge Seredenko` answered first, sorry I've to accept that one :) but I've voted up yours

Answer (score 1):

You can directly add multiple selectors with comma separated as below

```
$('.foo,.koo,.boo').removeClass('someClass');
```

**Edit 1:** After the edit in question, If you want to do this on the object level then try below.

```
  $.each([foo,koo,boo],function(i,v){
   v.removeClass('someClass');
  });
```

Comment: it's a good idea but I think this one is better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40900806/836979

Comment: oh nice!!! I didnt know about `add` feature

Comment: me too ! WOW JQuery thinked about everything !

Answer (score 0):

You can mix and match selectors like the following:

```
$('#someId, .foo, .boo').removeClass('someClass');
```